# face_recognition package can't work for me

Tags: ros, face-recognition

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I followed the guide [link text](http://wiki.ros.org/face_recognition),and input the followed commands

1. Publish /usb_cam/image_raw I'm using shows clearly my face
2. rosrun face_recognition Fserver
3. rosrun face_recognition Fclient
4. rostopic pub -1 /fr_order face_recognition/FRClientGoal -- 2 "your_name"

---

I got something in the terminal

### Fsever

1. [ INFO] [1489046351.126060180]: Training data loaded (25 training images of 1 people):
2. [ INFO] [1489046351.126147576]: People:
3. [ INFO] [1489046351.126162294]:
4. [ INFO] [1489046351.153610783]: show_screen_flag: true

### Fcilent

5. [ INFO] [1489046383.344315508]: request for sending goal [2] is received
6. [ INFO] [1489046383.344795519]: Goal just went active

---

if successful, what result can I expect? I can't find any picture new in the date package?

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/256566/face_recognition-package-can%27t-work-for-me/) by [michael_kong](https://answers.ros.org/users/29170/michael_kong/) on ROS Answers with karma: 41 on 2017-03-09

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I fixed it with the help of my friends.
in /home/michael/catkin_ws/src/procrob_functional/src --face_recognition.cpp

- change image_sub_ = it_.subscribe("/camera/image_raw", 1, &FaceRecognition::imageCB, this); to image_sub_ = it_.subscribe("/usb_cam/image_raw", 1, &FaceRecognition::imageCB, this);
- that is because I use "usb_cam" node not "camera" node

---

Originally posted by [michael_kong](https://answers.ros.org/users/29170/michael_kong/) with karma: 41 on 2017-03-09

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0